# concatMap fails to process all items in array

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am processing an array of files. For each file, I need to request the correct upload URL, and then upload that file to it's correct endpoint.

`concatMap` is supposed to emit only after the previous value has completed. In this way, the files should be processed sequentially.

Here is my code:

```
filesChanged(e) {

const files_raw = e.srcElement.files;

of(files_raw)
.pipe(
  flatMap((file) => file),
  tap((file) => console.log("Firing 1", file)),
  concatMap((file) => {
    return this.ms.fetchUploadURL().pipe(withLatestFrom(of(file)));
  }),
  tap((file) => console.log("Firing 2", file)),
  concatMap((values) => {
    return this.ms.uploadDirectToS3(values[0], values[1])
      .pipe(tap(value => console.log('From request', value)), withLatestFrom(of(values[0])));
  })
)
.subscribe(event => {
  console.log('In Subscribe', event);
});
}
```

If I attempt to upload 4 files, this code will log to the console the following output: 

`Firing 1
Firing 1
Firing 1
Firing 1
Firing 2
From request <value>
In Subscribe <value>`

**In other words, only the first file is processed and uploaded. All other files are seemingly ignored. Why is that?**

Shouldn't it start fetching the second URL once the first completes?

Also, if I change `concatMap` to `mergeMap`, then it does work but it processes all files at simultaneously, instead of sequentially. I thought passing the concurrency option to `mergeMap` might help, but acts identically to concatMap.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have tried to simulate your case here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ijfky6?devtoolsheight=60.
Note that I use `mergeMap` rather than `flatMap` but they are exactly the same.

According to such simulation, and to the logic I see implemented, what you get makes sense and you are probably seeing only 1 occurrence of 'Firing 2' because some error occurs in the second call to `uploadDirectToS3`. Maybe you should add an error function to `subscribe` as in the above simulation.

Said that, I guess there are few corrections you should put in your code to get what you want.

Let's start with a simple one. You can substitute

```
of(files_raw)
.pipe(
  flatMap((file) => file),
```

with the `from(files_raw)`.

Now let's enter the core of the point. You want to fetch the **url** to use via `this.ms.fetchUploadURL()` function (by the way, it surprises me that such function does not have any parameter, suggesting that it returns always the same value, but that's not relevant here). And then you want to call `this.ms.uploadDirectToS3` passing both the **url** and the **file** as parameters. If this is the case, than you should first call `this.ms.fetchUploadURL()` and then, via the operator `switchMap` ***switch*** to the other observable returned by `this.ms.uploadDirectToS3`. These operations should be performed within the `concatMap` so that you get them performed sequentially.

The final code could look something like this

```
from(files_raw)
.pipe(
  tap((file) => console.log("Firing 1", file)),
  concatMap((file) => {
    return fetchUploadURL().pipe(
      tap((file) => console.log("Firing 2", file)),
      switchMap(url => uploadDirectToS3(url, file))
    );
  }),
)
.subscribe(
  d => console.log('subscribe', d),
  err => console.error(err)
)
```

Here a simulation of the new code https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-whip1l?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Thanks for your thorough reply. Your answer make 100% sense...wrapping both http requests in the concatMap makes sense, however...it still doesn't work. No error is returned, the first file is always successful uploaded to AWS S3, but the second file never starts. It still hangs after the first 'subscribe' is logged out.

Comment: You may want to check the network log to see if the second request is ever fired. You may also want to look at what happens within the `uploadDirectToS3` method.

Answer (score 0):

My answer comes a bit late, but I'll post it for people ever experiencing similar issue:

It looks like

```
 this.ms.fetchUploadURL().pipe(withLatestFrom(of(file)))
```

**never completes**, which prevents concatMap from consuming (mapping) subsequent items.

I'm not JS developer, but in RxJava, one can reproduce your issue like that:

```
 Observable.just(1,2,3,4)
            .doOnComplete {  Log.d("TAG", "Complete 1") }
            .doOnNext { Log.d("TAG", "before concatMap $it") }
            .concatMap { someObservable(it) }
            .doOnComplete {  Log.d("TAG", "Complete 2") }
            .doOnNext { Log.d("TAG", "after concatMap $it") }
            .subscribe()
```

where `someObservable` implementation looks like below:

```
 fun observable(int: Int): Observable<Int> {
    return Observable.create {
        it.onNext(int)
    }
 }
```

Output for such implementation:

```
before concatMap 1
after concatMap 1
before concatMap 2
before concatMap 3
before concatMap 4
Complete 1
```

Concat map (Which is another observable) never completes, because mapper observables never complete.

Simply adding `onComplete()` in `someObservable` would fix the issue.
The output would look like below:

```
before concatMap 1
after concatMap 1
before concatMap 2
after concatMap 2
before concatMap 3
after concatMap 3
before concatMap 4
after concatMap 4
Complete 1
Complete 2
```

I think that in RxJS it's about the same.
Please check you mapper implementation.